# How to hide status bar on Android Q?

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I have trouble with hiding status bar on Android Q. When I hide it in split-view, it becomes white, instead of black. But if I'm not in split-view, everything is ok. 
How I do it:

```
public void hideSystemUI() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}
```

Is it just a bug or should I use some another way? I tried the way from official documentation, but it works terribly and the bar is white anyway.

NOTE: The problem it's white, not in that it's not hiding and only in split-screen mode. Fullscreen is not an option, I need to hide it dynamically. It's specific for Q only! It's not a duplicate. Please read carefully.

Answer (score 1):

@Abhinav's answer is correct, but if you want to go with the official documentation you should use `setSystemUiVisibility()`. Like this:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Also, set the theme in your `styles.xml` file, not in the manifest. Like this:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Add this to your styles.

For more information check out this: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status

If you still support API 16 and lower use @Abhinav's Code. It checks for both cases. If not then use the one listed here.

If you want to hide your toolbar try this code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Paste this inside your `styles.xml` file. Or if you want `Dark` replace the `Light` with `Dark` and remove `NoActionBar`.

Comment: that doesn't work. As I mentioned, I tried the way from the official documentation. The bar is still white on Q. The problem is that it's white, not in that I don't know hot to hide.

Comment: What do you mean it's white? Like it is hidden but white?

Comment: Try my edit, might help you